# "Top layer" plywood subfloor fastened to decking

Tags: subfloor, plywood, decking, fastening

I just tore out a ton of particle board subfloor that was previously used for carpeting.  The entire house has decking (2x6 planks) running on a 45 degree angle over joists with 3/8" plywood over the decking, with the exception of a few rooms where I tore out the particle board so just decking there.  I'm trying to figure out how to attach more 3/8" plywood to the decking where I tore out the particle board.  We are installing t n g hardwood eventually.

1. Should I try to drive decking screws through plywood into the joists, or can I just glue and screw into the decking?
2. Does the plywood need to be oriented perpendicular to the joists, even with the decking under already?  Or should I orient the plywood so that it will run perpendicular to the hardwood we will install (so, parallel to the joists..)
3. Should I take the time to level the plywood subfloor over the decking, or should I just wait until installing the actual hardwood tongue and groove to worry about leveling (or "flattening, as I suppose it will be)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 45 degree decking is the primary sub-floor.  It's a technique that was widely used in the past, but has subsequently been replaced with simply dropping sheets of plywood down.

In answer to your questions:

1) You can glue and screw to the sub-floor.

2) In this case, it doesn't matter.  The sub-floor is carrying the load diagonally.  However, if there were no sub-floor, then you would want to go perpendicular. See [this discussion on the subject](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/9325/how-is-installing-roof-sheathing-horizontally-stronger-than-vertically).

3) Always - always - always level as you go.  Fix the level at the soonest possible opportunity or it can be amplified by an order of magnitude.